# Do you need an opening <html> tag?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, initializr

I use [Initializer](http://www.initializr.com/) to quickly generate HTML5 + Boostrap boilerplates and am curious why the HTML doc that is created does not have an opening `<html>` tag?

Here is the top portion of what Initializr generates for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
```

I have deployed a few websites using Initializr and haven't run into problems. Do you need an opening `<html>` tag?

Comment: there's 4 `<html>` tags there. They're fenced in by IE conditional tags, but there's still 4 tags in there. just because they have a class attribute doesn't turn into `<not-html>`

Comment: What do you mean that it doesn't have an opening `html` tag? I see `html` tags in your code.

Comment: There is only one `<html>` tag in the code. Text in comments does not constitute a tag. IE processes certain types of comments in a nonconforming way, but that’s a different issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [HTML 5 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#the-html-element):

> An html element's start tag can be omitted if the first thing inside the html element is not a comment.
>   An html element's end tag can be omitted if the html element is not immediately followed by a comment.

So, yes, the tag is optional.

Comment: Yet, OP's code doesn't actually omit it, nor it can be omitted if you want to assign a class or ID to it from HTML.

Comment: It is correct, the code posted does contain an `<html>` tag, but the question specifically asks if it's required. Ironic that they're not actually using code which supports the question...